# creating external table from compressed (gz format) files without selecting all fields

Tags: sql, hive, external-tables

I have gz files in a folder. I need only 3 columns from these files, but each line has over 100 of them. At the moment I create a view this way.

```
drop table MAK_CHARGE_RCR;
create external table MAK_CHARGE_RCR
(LINE string)
STORED as SEQUENCEFILE
LOCATION '/apps/hive/warehouse/mydb.db/file_rcr';

drop view VW_MAK_CHARGE_RCR;
create view VW_MAK_CHARGE_RCR as
Select LINE[57] as CREATE_DATE, LINE[64] as SUBS_KEY, LINE[63] as RC_TERM_NAME 
from
    (Select split(LINE, '\\|') as LINE
    from MAK_CHARGE_RCR) a;
```

The view has the fields I need. Now I have to do the same, but without CTAS and I am not sure how to go about it. What can I do?

I was told the table must look like this

```
create external table MAK_CHARGE_RCR
(CREATE_DATE string, SUBS_KEY string, RC_TERM_NAME etc)
```

I could split the line like this

```
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\\|'
```

but I'll need to list every column. I have another group of files with over 1000 columns. All of them I'll need to list. This just seems a bit excessive, so I wondered if it is possible to do

```
create external table arstel.MAK_CHARGE_RCR
(split(LINE, '\\|')[57] string,
split(LINE, '\\|')[64] string
etc)
```

This doesn't work obviously, but maybe there are work arounds?

Comment: Not clear. What do you mean by "Now I have to do the same, but without CTAS"?

Comment: @Dudu Updated the question.

Comment: O.K. This can be solved using RegEx Serde. Hoever your original solution seems reasonable and I don't get the " I was told the table must look like this" part. What do "they" have against your solution?

Comment: @Dudu False alarm! Seems like this doesn't apply in my case. But the way it was explained, is that there are tables in production(?), their structure can change and because of that my scripts should not depend on them when I create my tables. In this case `MAK_CHARGE_RCR` is made by me, so everything's fine. Does that make sense?

Comment: With that logic we won't work with tables. Ever. :-) Tables may change but 99.99999% of the time it's addition of columns or size changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**RegexSerDe**

For educational purposes

P.s.
I intend to create an enhanced version of the CSV SerDe that excepts an additional parameter with the positions of the requested columns.

#### Demo

**bash**

```
echo {a..c}{1..100} | xargs -n 100 | tr ' ' '|'  | \
hdfs dfs -put - /user/hive/warehouse/mytable/data.txt
```

**hive**

```
create external table mytable
(
    col58   string
   ,col64   string
   ,col65   string
)
row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
with serdeproperties ("input.regex" = "^(?:([^|]*)\\|){58}(?:([^|]*)\\|){6}([^|]*)\\|.*$")
stored as textfile
location '/user/hive/warehouse/mytable'
;
```

---

```
select * from mytable
;
```

---

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| mytable.col58 | mytable.col64 | mytable.col65 |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| a58           | a64           | a65           |
| b58           | b64           | b65           |
| c58           | c64           | c65           |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```